# performing rfec in python and understanding output

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection, rfe

I am doing [rfecv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) in python using pandas. my step size is 1. I start with 174 features. My function call is as below

```
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'), step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=44),scoring='recall',\
              min_features_to_select=30, verbose=0)
rfecv.fit(X_train, y['tag'])
```

Optimal number of features returned by rfecv is 89. I noticed that length of `cv_results_['mean_test_score']` is 145.

Shouldn't it be 174-89=85? If `RFECV` removes 1 feature at a time and ends up with 89 features out of 174 then I felt that there will be 85 steps (length of `'mean_test_score'`).

```
#adding some dummy example-------------------------
```

In below case, we start with 150 features. minimum features to select is 3 and it selects 4 features. But then why `print (len(selector.cv_results_['std_test_score']))` is 148 if 1 feature is eliminated at a time

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=150, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, min_features_to_select=3)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
print (selector.support_)
print (selector.ranking_)
print (selector.n_features_)

print (len(selector.cv_results_['std_test_score']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you start with 174 features and end up with 89 features as the optimal number. The length of `cv_results_['mean_test_score']` being 145 is due to the cross-validation process. The RFECV method does not just eliminate one feature at a time but performs cross-validation at each step to estimate the model's performance with a different number of features. So, it evaluates the model multiple times during the feature selection process with different subsets of features.

You start with 174 features. The RFECV starts the feature elimination process, evaluates the model's performance using cross-validation (here, with 10-fold stratified cross-validation), and records the mean test score for each step.
After eliminating some features, the process enters the second step, where the number of features might differ from 174 (depending on how many were eliminated in the first step).
The process continues until it reaches the stopping criterion, either the `min_features_to_select` or the number of features where the performance does not improve significantly.

The length of `cv_results_['mean_test_score']` will give you the number of steps taken during the feature elimination process, which may not equal the difference between the initial and final number of features selected.

In your second example with 150 features, when you set `min_features_to_select=3`, the process will select at least 3 features. However, it might select more features if that leads to better performance during cross-validation. Hence, the length of `cv_results_['std_test_score']` is 148, indicating that the RFECV has evaluated the model's performance at 148 different steps (with different subsets of features).

I created a simple example with 10 features to demonstrate the RFECV process :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# Generate synthetic data with 10 features and 100 samples
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=10, random_state=42)

# Define the estimator and RFECV parameters
estimator = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=44)
step_size = 1
min_features_to_select = 3

# Create the RFECV object and fit it to the data
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=estimator, step=step_size, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy', 
              min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select, verbose=0)
rfecv.fit(X, y)

# Get the optimal number of features selected
optimal_num_features = rfecv.n_features_

# Get the mean test scores during the feature selection process
mean_test_scores = rfecv.cv_results_['mean_test_score']

# Print the results
print("Optimal number of features selected:", optimal_num_features)
print("Number of steps in RFECV:", len(mean_test_scores))
```

The output :

[image]

Since min_features_to_select=3, the RFECV process will select at least 3 features. The number of steps in RFECV will depend on how many features are eliminated during the cross-validation process at each step.

Comment: is there any official source that confirms that `which may not equal the difference between the initial and final number of features selected.`

Comment: The RFECV algorithm, as implemented in scikit-learn, aims to find the optimal subset of features that maximizes the performance metric (e.g., accuracy, recall, etc.) while performing cross-validation at each step. This iterative process can lead to variations in the number of steps taken during feature elimination, making it different from the difference in the initial and final number of features. Not mentioned explicitly but this is what I get in many formus and analyzing the behavior of it https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html